# How to add padding or margin according to different screen sizes

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, responsive

I want to give padding or margin according to screen sizes.

Below is code and images of two different sizes screens with same padding.

This is my code:

```
    Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 160, left: 90, bottom: 20),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/logo.png',
                  height: 70,
                  width: 70,
                ),
                Text(
                  '  Whatsapp',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

My real device

[image]

Android Studio emulator

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can create two methods that accept BuildContext

```
double deviceHeight(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

double deviceWidth(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

And if you want uniform margin regardless of device width or height, use it like this

```
Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: deviceHeight(context) * 0.3,
          left: deviceWidth(context) * 0.09,
          bottom: deviceHeight(context) * 0.06,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'assets/logo.png',
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
            ),
            Text(
              '  Whatsapp',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

`deviceHeight(context) * 0.3` simply means 30% of the screen Height, `deviceWidth(context) * 0.09` means 9% of the screen Width & `bottom: deviceHeight(context) * 0.06` means 6% of the screen Height

The advantage here is that you can adjust the figures to match, and it will take equal spacing on any device.

Comment: I follow exact same as you showed here, and it shows an error- Invalid constant value.

Comment: Note you cannot use the above in a const expression. Ex: `const Container(height: deviceHeight(context) * 0.6, child: Text("Hello World!"),);` This will result in an error. As the value of that function cannot be determined during compilation.

Answer (score 4):

Your can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to get height of your screen and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to get width of your screen.

According to your image, it will be better to use Flex widgets like [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), [`Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html), [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) to adjust the spacing between the widgets inside Column.

Answer (score 1):

use flutter_screenutil

change code to:

```
 Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 160.w, left: 90.w, bottom: 20.w),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/logo.png',
                  height: 70.w,
                  width: 70.w,
                ),
                Text(
                  '  Whatsapp',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26.sp,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

In w, h, r, you can use w first, and then you can choose the corresponding one according to the actual situation.

Answer (score -1):

in terms of android and IOS we can easily say that the padding in android commonly used as 16 and in case of IOS padding for an commom page is 18